# Copy the value in a new sheet if the column value of one sheet matches the another in excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am new to VB scripts so I need help to perform the below task.
What I require is to do 3 things:

1. Match the value of col A, row by row, of sheet 1 with the value in any row of col A of sheet 2.
2. If it matches then it has to copy that value in col A of new sheet in the same workbook.
3. Now the remaining col of sheet 2 i.e. col B and more will be appended and copied to new sheet where we have earlier copied the matched col A values.

For an Example:
Sheet1 Data:

```
employeeName   ID  Dept
Mohan          1   IT
```

Sheet2 Data:

```
employeeName   ID  In time      Out time
Gyaan          2   12:00:00 PM  10:15:00 PM
Mohan          1   09:02:00 AM  11:01:00 PM
```

Now Sheet 3 should have:

```
employeeName   ID  Intime       Out time
Mohan          1   09:02:00 AM  11:01:00 PM
```

This is all in a same workbook and need to be done using VBA.

Comment: To go further on @enderland's question, see the [FAQ]:<www.stackoverflow.com/faq>. You will get help A LOT faster, if you show us the code you've tried and where it's failing, rather than asking us to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in a Module in the workbook and execute the run() sub. This assumes that the code names of your sheets are Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3 as you described.

```
Sub run()

    Dim row As Integer, sheet2Row As Integer
    row = 2

    With Sheet1
        Do While (.Cells(row, 1) <> "")
            sheet2Row = findInSheet2(.Cells(row, 1))
            If sheet2Row <> 0 Then copyRow (sheet2Row)
            row = row + 1
        Loop
    End With

End Sub

Function findInSheet2(text As String) As Integer

    Dim found As Range

    With Sheet2
        Set found = .Columns(1).Find(What:=text, MatchCase:=True)
        If Not found Is Nothing Then
            findInSheet2 = found.row
        Else
            findInSheet2 = 0
        End If
    End With

End Function

Sub copyRow(row As Integer)

    Sheet2.Rows(row).Copy
    Sheet3.Rows(getSheet3LastRow).PasteSpecial

End Sub

Function getSheet3LastRow()

    Dim found As Range

    Set found = Sheet3.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        getSheet3LastRow = found.row + 1
    Else
        getSheet3LastRow = 1
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Mattboy..it is working perfectly fine ...but I am facing a problem in this code...which is like: I am having duplicte values in Sheet 2 i.e, redundant values but using this code..it is showing single first matching row. I need to have all matching row in sheet3.

Comment: This is some awesome stuff!!